# LogonUser 1326 crossdomain error

Tags: c#, windows, security

using the impersonation code from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx

I can impersonate a user on the same domain with no problem but trying a user on another domain with credentials I have verified always fails with error 1326 "unknown user name or bad password".

Read an a lot of blog posts but nothing is getting me any closer to a resolution.
any ideas ?

using the 'run as user' does work for other domain user so it is possible.

edit: 'run as user' works when using SQL Management Studio.

scenario 1: user on domain A executes SQL MS via 'run as user' for domain B.

result: SQL MS allows access to database on domain B.

scenario 2: user on domain A executes SQL MS as user of domain A.

result: SQL MS denies access to database on domain B.

Domain B is NOT trusted by domain A or vsv however scenario 1 does work.

How can I replicate scenario 1 programmatically  ?

What is SQL MS doing to pass through the untrusted user details via 'run as user' ?

Comment: Can you login with that domain+user name?  The sysadmins live at serverfault.com

Comment: yes, that is why I posting this as programming issue.

Comment: I dont know how scenario 1 would work. I know it does not work for me.